# How do I expand the hard drive partition of an OSX guest OS in VirtualBox when the disk has been enlarged?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, virtualbox

My host system is running OSX El Capitan 10.11.5 and VirtualBox 5.0.22 r108108

Using the [information found in another answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211722/33458), I was successfully able to extract an ISO of my host operating system and install it as a guest OS in a VirtualBox VM.  I had to leave the settings of my VM as the defaults during creation, which led me to only have a hard disk size of 20GB, but I have successfully booted into the guest OS and have a partition of 20GB.

Now I want to increase the size of my virtual hard disk to 40GB.  I used the following command to modify the vdi file:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd test1.vdi --resize 40960
```

However, Disk Utility is unable to recognize that the drive is now 40GB and I am unable to expand the partition.  I have tried both the Disk Utility program after a full boot as well as the Disk Utility present on the ISO when I boot from it.

How do I get the OSX guest OS to recognize a larger hard drive and expand the partition accordingly?

Comment: You said, "_I had to leave the settings of my VM as the defaults during creation, which led me to only have a hard disk size of 20GB_"... Why did you have to leave it at 20 GB?  I had no problem resizing the HDD before completing the Create Virtual Machine wizard and installing OS X.

Comment: Both my coworker and myself tried to change the HDD size to 40GB during the wizard and the VM simply showed a black screen when trying to boot the installation media.  We were unable to actually install the guest OS and figured it was a bug.  If you think you can help with this, I can open up a new question.